# Check for working AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have some work to do in the another thread (by doingAsyncTask).
Work start when user click on button. But at the same time 
only one object of doingAsyncTask must do this work, i meen if doingAsyncTask is working, then click on button must not create a new object of doingAsyncTask and execute it, it must wait until work finish. How can i check it?

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //....
    }

    public void onclickButton(View view) {
        new doingAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    public class doingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        //doing something
        return(null);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
   }
}
```

**SOLVED**
thx all , its works for me

```
      if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
            task=new ProgressBarShow();
        if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
            //task=new ProgressBarShow();
            task.execute();
        }
```

Comment: There are many alternatives, for instance, disable button once it was clicked, then re-enable it after AsyncTask finish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)

```
AsyncTask.Status    FINISHED    Indicates that onPostExecute(Result) has finished. 
AsyncTask.Status    PENDING     Indicates that the task has not been executed yet. 
AsyncTask.Status    RUNNING     Indicates that the task is running.
```

**code:**

```
if (doingAsyncTask().getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
     doingAsyncTask().execute();
else
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    doingAsyncTask asyncTask; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
       // ...
       asyncTask = new doingAsyncTask();   
    }
    public void onclickButton(View view) {
         if(ayncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) || ayncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
             asyncTask.execute();
         }
         else {
             // do something
         }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but i have no object?? im right that each time AsyncTask create new objec? so where check for status??

Comment: doingAsyncTask is a reference object of your AsyncTask --- sory, what is it ?

Comment: the same problem, AsyncTask need to create new object each execute

Comment: its near, but not working ) look at my solution at the top, thx u!

Comment: but you write yourself : AsyncTask.Status    PENDING     Indicates that the task has not been executed yet. PENDING != RUNNING.. why wrong?

Comment: after execute, when finished ill get this status and the create new object

Comment: I combine both condition in one, Now you can use the only one if condition. and also make a new object in it. Look at my answer.

Comment: you need asyncTask = new doingAsyncTask();  before asyncTask.execute(); cause if status will be finished it ll not working

Comment: just read my above comment carefully.. "make a new object in it."

Answer (score 2):

You can check the status of AsyncTask => [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)

For example:

```
    myAsyncTask mtask = new myAsyncTask();
    mtask.execute();

   // write this wherever you want to check status
   if(mtask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        // My AsyncTask is done and onPostExecute was called
    }
```

Comment: you create new object befor execute, checking this object - it will never be running

Comment: // it was just for idea. If i give object name then again a question will raise that `what is mtask actually`? thats why i have written that line.

Comment: the main question is : AsyncTask have to create new object each execute, so check status of new object isnt helpful, u know

Comment: Hello sir, I want to call 3 asynctask in main activity simultaneously.i was given this solution but it not working.just first asynctask call then another inside condition not called..dont know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you checked why next asynctask is not getting called? Why that condition is not getting called? I can't help without seeing what you are doing exactly but Debug can help you for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[getStatus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29)** of AsyncTask to check its status before setting a new task

Answer (score 0):

The code could be like this:

```
doingAsyncTask task;
public void onclickButton(View view) {
    if(task==null){
        task=new doingAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
    }
    else if(task.Status!=RUNNING){
        task=new doingAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: you create new object befor execute, checking this object - it will never be running

Comment: this will not work too, AsyncTask need to create new object each execute

Comment: no, when you click second time , status will be finished and click do nothing, look at my solution, thx